# Can't run command as Administrator

Tags: powershell

On one of our Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, I can't run `Get-ScheduledTask` as an Administrator. I can run it as normal user. Following is the error message, I receive when I try to execute the command, if I run PowerShell as an Admin.

```
Get-ScheduledTask : The parameter is incorrect.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ScheduledTask
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...T_ScheduledTask) [Get-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Get-ScheduledTask
```

Can someone please advise, why is it so?

Comment: Can you show the full command you're running ? coz the error message states a parameter is incorrect, means you are passing something else with the `Get-SheduledTask`

Comment: Thats the full command mate. Even I am confused with the error message. I am not passing any argument at all

Comment: Ok i just checked this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e65337b0-ffa0-4de4-b67b-dcaa1018476b/problems-with-getscheduledtask?forum=winserverpowershell and it seems to be a framework issue, can you try running the command after a system restart

Comment: Thanks mate. Restart fixed this issue. :) (Should have thought about it before)

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer, so that you can  get some points. :)

Comment: done man, Thanks :) Thumbs up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a transient framework issue. Restart the machine should fix it .
[Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e65337b0-ffa0-4de4-b67b-dcaa1018476b/problems-with-getscheduledtask?forum=winserverpowershell)